# More than 1 (insert, update) trigger on a table doesn't work - why? Is it possible?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

**My question**

Can I have 2 Insert,Update triggers on the same table and have them both work.

I have 3 tables all with the exact same schema `TestTable, TestTable2, TestTable3`
Schema is as follows for convenience I have the create-schema commands under the trigger code:

PK - int (this is the Primary KEY)
Name- vcharchar(10)
TheValue - int

They attempt to synchronise inserted and updated rows in TestTable with TestTable2 and TestTable3

If I disable 1 trigger the other works, and vice-versa.

My QUESTION> Can both triggers work on the table

2 triggers and schema defined below:

```
    USE [WQMetaData]
GO

/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[TESTTABLETRIGGER]    Script Date: 05/03/2018 10:59:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TESTTABLETRIGGER] 
   ON  [dbo].[testtable]
   AFTER INSERT, update
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @thevalue int,@pk int, @existingPK int
    set @existingPK = 0
    select @thevalue= thevalue from inserted
    select @pk = pk from inserted
    select @existingPK =  pk from WQMetaData.dbo.TESTTABLE2 where pk = @pk


    if @existingPK <= 0
    begin
    Insert into WQMetaData.dbo.TESTTABLE2 (pk,name, thevalue)

    select
    inserted.pk,
    inserted.name,
    inserted.thevalue
    from inserted
end
if @pk > 0 
begin
    update    WQMetaData.dbo.TESTTABLE2 set thevalue = @thevalue where pk = @pk

    end 
END



GO

**2nd trigger**
USE [WQMetaData]
GO

/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[TESTTABLETRIGGER2]    Script Date: 05/03/2018 11:00:47 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TESTTABLETRIGGER2] 
   ON  [dbo].[testtable]
   AFTER INSERT, update
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @thevalue int,@pk int, @existingPK int
    set @existingPK = 0
    select @thevalue= thevalue from inserted
    select @pk = pk from inserted
    select @existingPK =  pk from WQMetaData.dbo.TESTTABLE2 where pk = @pk


if @existingPK <= 0
    begin
      Insert into WQMetaData.dbo.TESTTABLE3 (pk,name, thevalue)
        select
        inserted.pk,
        inserted.name,
        inserted.thevalue
        from inserted
    end

if @pk > 0 
   begin
    update    WQMetaData.dbo.TESTTABLE3 set thevalue = @thevalue where pk = @pk
   end 
END




GO
USE [WQMetaData]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[testtable]    Script Date: 05/03/2018 11:33:29 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testtable](
    [PK] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [varchar](12) NOT NULL,
    [TheValue] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Comment: Your triggers have a MAJOR flaw. They assume there will only every be a single row in inserted or deleted. This is not how triggers work in sql server. They fire once per operation, not once per row. As such your triggers needs to be set based. And having multiple triggers for the same operation is supported but is a real pain to deal with. It is generally best to combine them into a single trigger, just for maintenance.

Comment: As @SeanLange said, treat `inserted` as a regular table and this will make sense. Your variable declarations are only selecting the first row from `inserted`.

Comment: @JacobH - separate assignments mean they're not even all guaranteed to retrieve data from the *same* row, let alone this mysterious "first" row you allude to.

Comment: @Damien_the_unbeliever what would I have done without your passive aggressive correction on my passing comment??

Comment: @JacobH: I find your reference to *passive agressive* offensive and biased toward [quality concerned users who have made this site a success](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366858/62576). Please don't be rude. Aren't we trying to [Be nice](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)